# How to make actions that are session-dependent without falling in 'nil' situations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, null

So I basically made a 'session-dependent' action (Not the action/controller but behavior), and this is it (in my application layout) :

---

```
unless session[:user_id]
   link_to('Add', {:controller => 'somecontroller', :action => 'someActionThatNeedsNoID'})
  return false
else
link_to('Add', {:controller => 'somecontroller', :action => 'someActionThatNeedsID', :user_id => @connected_user})
   return true
end
```

---

And in my `application controller`, I made a function that creates an instance of the currently connected user , if connected.

---

```
def sessionr
        unless session[:user_id]
            return false # halts the before_action
          else
            @id_for_dd = session[:user_id]
                    #  Get the user 
           @connected_user = User.find_by({:id => @id_for_dd})
                    # Get the user
            return true
         end
      end
```

---

And everything works just fine, only when I log out, I get this error:

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

---

pointing at

---

```
else
    link_to('Add', {:controller => 'somecontroller', :action => 'someActionThatNeedsID', :user_id => @connected_user})
       return true
```

---

**More details :**

---

In my logout action :

```
  def logout
    session[:user_id] = nil
    session[:username] = nil
    flash[:notice] = "Logged out"
    redirect_to(:action => "login")
  end
```

---

I fully grasp the error, however I do not seem to get any ideas on how to prevent this when I log out...

Is there a way to ignore the code that containes the `connected_user` when it is nil (when logged out) ?

---

**Update#1 : Solved**

---

The problem was mainly with the before action filter, I had the `before_action :sessionr`
before  `before_action :confirm_logged_in`

That seemed to solve it, I don't know much about how it got solved, if you provide an answer to how did that happen, I'll take it as the right answer.

More details :

The confirm_logged_in function :

```
  def confirm_logged_in
    unless session[:user_id]
      flash[:notice] = "Veulliez Se connecter"
      redirect_to(:controller => 'access', :action => 'login')
      return false # halts the before_action
    else
      return true
     end
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `else` to `elsif !connected_user.nil?` and it should ignore the code when the user is nil.

Comment: I'll take your answer as the solution because my question was mainly how to ignore that block of code.